# Correct no of days/weeks between 2 days?

Tags: php

I have created a function to work out the amount of days and then weeks between 2 dates, in the example below there is 35 days resulting exactly 5 weeks, however the function is returning just short of this at 4.8571428571429 - the division is killing the remainder and coming out at 4.

I could use the ceil function to round it up to 5 but is this this a safe method for all dates? or is there a better way to do it?

```
    $date1 = new DateTime('2015-02-23');
    $date2 = new DateTime('2015-03-29');

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");

    $weeks = $diff / 7;

    return $weeks;
```

Comment: To round up: `round("4.8571428571429", 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Comment: This probably has to do with the idea of inclusive/exclusive range. The answer you are getting is actually 34/7. Meaning the diff() is not including the bounding date at one end.

Comment: try Round [link]http://php.net/round

Comment: The  difference between these two is 32 days, which is not a full 5 weeks. How *should* your algorithm behave for non-full week divisions...?

Comment: I hope you know that between 2015-02-23 and 2015-03-27 there are less then 35 days?

Comment: Ok, after your update, everything is right: now you have 34 days.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake it 2015-03-29. If i count from 23rd Feb to 29th March i end up with 35.

Comment: between those dates is 5 whole weeks from the monday to sunday, 5*7=35

Answer (score 3):

```
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Use this line after your $date2 initialisation.

Why will this work?
If you count, you have 34 days now: FROM 23-02 0:00 TILL 29-03 0:00.

If you want to count this last day also (to have 35 days), you'll need to add an extra day.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but still confused that I am counting wrong, from 23rd feb to 29th march I count exactly 5 weeks which is 35 days.

Comment: You count from midnight to midnight. If you count from monday till tuesday, you'll have 1 day, because you only have counted till the beginning of the tuesday, not till the end. So the last day (sunday 29 march) is not included, so you need to add an extra day.

Answer (score 1):

Add a single day to $date2

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2015-02-23');
$date2 = new DateTime('2015-03-29');
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");

$weeks = $diff / 7;

return $weeks;
```

However, you still don't have a whole number of weeks difference with your original dates

Comment: This looks like it has a retaliatory DV, so +1.